# dereferencing with different types of the same size gives different results

Tags: c, printf

Why does the type used to derefernce pointers passed to printf affect the output, even if the types are the same size:

```
void test_double(void *x)
{
    double *y = x;
    uint64_t *z = x;
    printf("double/double: %lf\n", *y);
    printf("double/uint64: %lf\n", *z);
    printf("uint64/double: 0x%016llx\n", *y);
    printf("uint64/uint64: 0x%016llx\n", *z);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
    double x = 1.0;
    test_double(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
double/double: 1.000000
double/uint64: 1.000000
uint64/double: 0x00007f00e17d7000
uint64/uint64: 0x3ff0000000000000
```

I would have expected the last two lines to both correctly print 0x3ff0000000000000, the representation of 1.0 in an IEEE754 double floating point.

Comment: Which compiler are you using on what platform? Gcc 4.5.3 under Cygwin prints 0x3ff0..0 for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Undefined Behavior.  The C language standard says that if the variadic arguments don't have the type implied by the format string, then that's UB.  In your third print statement, you're passing a `double`, but it's expecting a `uint64_t`.  Since it's UB, anything can happen.

This specification allows the implementation to do things like pass integers on the stack but floating-point values through the FPU registers, which is what I suspect is happening in your test case.  For example, the [cdecl calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) on Linux on x86 (GCC) passes floating-point function arguments on the x87 pseudo-stack (registers `ST0...ST7`).

If you look at the generated assembly, you'll probably discover why your third and fourth print statements are behaving differently.  On Mac OS X 10.8.2 64-bit with Clang 4.1, I was able to reproduce similar results, and the assembly looked like this, which I've annotated:

```
        .section        __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl  _test_double
        .align  4, 0x90
_test_double:                           ## @test_double
        .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
        pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
        .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
        .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
        pushq   %rbx
        pushq   %rax
Ltmp6:
        .cfi_offset %rbx, -24

    # printf("%lf", double)
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        movsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
        leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdi
        movb    $1, %al
        callq   _printf

    # printf("%lf", uint64_t)
        movq    (%rbx), %rsi
        leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rdi
        xorb    %al, %al
        callq   _printf

    # printf("%llx", double)
        leaq    L_.str2(%rip), %rdi
        movsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
        movb    $1, %al
        callq   _printf

    # printf("%llx", uint64_t)
        leaq    L_.str3(%rip), %rdi
        movq    (%rbx), %rsi
        xorb    %al, %al
        addq    $8, %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %rbp
        jmp     _printf                 ## TAILCALL
        .cfi_endproc
```

In the case of printing a `double` value, it's putting the argument into the [SIMD `%xmm0` register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions):

```
movsd   (%rbx), %xmm0
```

But in the case of a `uint64_t` value, it's passing the argument through the integer register `%rsi`:

```
movq    (%rbx), %rsi
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I'm not used to x86 assembly, most of my assembly experience has been done with simpler RISC systems (which don't have the separate FPU stack).

Comment: Good answer.  I think the "... third print statement, you're passing a uint64_t, but it's expecting a double" might be the other way around.